# How can I configure an Ubuntu machine based off another machine's settings

Tags: configuration, settings

The company that I work for gives us remote access to development machines with limited privileges. Developers are not allowed to install software on these dev machines unless approved by higher-ups (all political bull I can't do anything about now), and that presents a problem for me because I am unable to install debugging tools, we devs do not belong to the sudo group, and I can't install cloning tools too. So I thought, why not install VM in my physical machine and re-create the environment in order for me to debug web apps.

How much can I accomplish in doing this without having sudo permissions to my remote dev machine? Is this as simple to do as copying configs and settings over to my local machine? Could you recommend a guide or an approach to accomplish this task?

Remote Dev Machine: AWS Platform Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS Bionic